# Moving an Object over an array of JButtons (java)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have an array of JButtons used as a map for a tower defense game.  Now I am adding the enemies to move across the path.  Is there a way to paint the buttons so that the enemies move fluid over the buttons and not just jump from button to button?

EDIT: the decision was to go with JLayeredPane to paint over the buttons.

Comment: Can you post some of the code you've tried?

Comment: Or an example of the look you want to achieve? It's hard to imagine without a photo reference to your JFrame

Comment: Look into [`JLayeredPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html)..

Comment: If you are using an image, you can draw a section of an image, so just cut the image and draw the image individually.

Comment: I wouldn't be using `JButtons` at all for an animated game.  Look into OpenGL, Java has several binding for that API.

Comment: Use "setLayout(null)" for the JComponent containing your JButtons and place them as well as your enemies using "setBounds()". It gives you more fluidity.